# Missing Properties in Active Directory's ResultPropertyCollection

Tags: c#

I have a `ResultPropertyCollection` object called `resultValues`.

I can view info about an AD user (eg their name) using this code:

```
resultValues["name"][0].ToString()
```

If I look up a user in Outlook's address book, I can see all the same info that I can see in C# as well as a photo of the user.

If Outlook is able to display the user's photo, why is it that `resultValues["jpegPhoto"][0].ToString()` and `resultValues["photo"][0].ToString()` throw System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Wouldn't Outlook use the [jpegPhoto attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676813%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's picture attribute, the attribute has Ldap-Display-Name `thumbnailPhoto`.
Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680034(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out, I need to use this attribute:

```
resultValues["thumbnailPhoto"][0];
```

However, why can't I find this attribute in the schema on MSDN?

(Answer found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fc45bfd3-8a85-46cc-a687-95b99291ae1a/get-the-user-thumbnail-picture-from-active-directory?forum=csharpgeneral)